# In Socket.IO, what is the "io" cookie used for?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, engine.io

I know it is a session cookie, but for which purpose does Socket.IO actually use the `io` cookie? I know I can disable it, but couldn't find anything else on [the docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/). Why is it enabled by default and what I'm going to lose or break if I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently and according to an answer to [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2276) Github issue, "it's not used for anything" so it's safe to disable it.